# How to create simple file based distributions for Windows Services and Windows Applications via MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, package, publish

Firstly, thanks for taking the time to read and possibly comment on this question.

**Summary**

How can I use MSBuild to automatically package MS Visual Studio Windows Services and Windows Applications into simple (a directory of files including the dlls, exes, configs etc) which I can release to our Dev-Ops dept. I do not want the distribution in MSI installer or setup.exe or some web deployment format which appear to be the default in MS Visual Studio's publish.

**My Environment**

- Windows XP SP3 (32-bit), Window Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)
- .NET 4.0 (32-bit)
- MS Visual Studio 2010 (32-bit)
- NAnt 0.91 (32-bit)

**My Scenario**

Currently, we have about 5 types of MS Visual Studio project and for the first 3 types (Web Services, Web Applications, Web Sites), we can use MSBuild to package the source into a simple directory of files (distribution) based on the contents of the csproj file using:

msbuild my.component.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Package /p:_PackageTempDir="C:\temp\some\dir"

For the latter 2 types (Windows Services, Windows Applications), we cannot use MSBuild as above. From investigation via the Publish command in Visual Studio, it appears that I can create setup.exe installers for both Windows Services and Windows Applications but this is not what I want - I just want to be able to create a simple directory of files (distribution) as I have been doing for the other project types. I accept that this may not be possible but I would just like to know for sure.

**Conclusions**

Thus far, for both Windows Services and Windows Applications I have come to the following conclusions, the former two, not ideal:

- Use MSBuild to compile the code and NAnt to create the simple directory of files (distribution).
- Use MSBuild to compile the code and create a post build event to create the distribution.
- Your suggestion here (much appreciated).

Comment: So, I'm a little confused what you want as output.  An installer?  A directory of files? A script used to install your Windows Services?

Comment: I splattered bits. Thanks for reading. I have updated the question to address your questions. A directory of files for both Windows Services and Windows Applications is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research online (MSDN), at StackOverflow and limited local experimentation, it appears that both Windows Services and Windows Applcations cannot be quickly or easily built in a way which is similar to the distribution output of MSBuild's package command, that is, into a local file-based distribution.

For Windows Applications, as Splattered Bits suggested, the contents of the release bin directory can be used as the simple file-based distribution after the project has been compiled.

For Windows Services, it is be possible to do what we did for Windows Applications above and use the output from the release bin directory.

In both cases, a change to the CSPROJ file may be required to suppress the creation of PDB files or futher configuration the compilation output.

Answer (score 0):

First, .Net managed Windows services, just as their unmanaged counterparts, must be registered with the Windows Service Controller via a command line tool called InstallUtil. There are different versions of this utility for the various .Net Framework versions. You will find them where the .Net framework gets installed. On my development box, for example, they are located under the individual framework subfolders of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.

Second, perhaps you could clarify what specific problems you are seeing with the Windows Application distributions. These are normally as easily done as simple file distributions as web sites and web services are.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your response. Our Dev-Ops team install the Windows service - we have nothing to do with this activity and only have to worry about the requirement of creating the release distribution which, in the case of the Windows Service, contains a service exe, dlls, the app config, log4net config and some custom batch files to call out to InstallUitl to install the service. We just provide that collection of files. The issue with the Windows Application is that it can only be published as an install, rather than a collection of files (ie: most of the \bin\release directory).

Answer (score 0):

You can run MSBuild to get what you want, you just need to specify a different target than `Package`.  I believe you want `Build':

```
msbuild my.component.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build
```

You can customize the build output directory via a property, but I can't remember off the top of my head what that property name is.  If you crack open your csproj file, you should be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is currently what we do for both the Windows Services and the Windows Applications. However, we are still left with a \bin directory under the component and no nice clean file based distribution directory like with MSBuild's package. So, after running your above target, we execute a NAnt distribution target, that takes the contents (dlls, exes, configs) of the \bin directory under the component and manipulates it into a cleaner distribution structure like what MSBuild's package does. I'll look into MSBuild's properties more and if I figure it out, I'll post it.

Comment: @surfjungle What do you want the output structure to look like?  I've never seen an MSBuild package before.

Comment: MSBuild's package command is just like MS Visual Studio's publish tool. It compiles the CS file and then collects all the required distributable files such as DLLs, EXEs and config and where applicable, those listed in the CSPROJ file and puts them into a distribution directory which I specify via MSBuild - very handy and unlike a straight compile via MSBuild, this means I don't have to write a custom deployment infrastructure in NAnt to pull all the required compiled and static (ASPX, JS, ASHX, ASMX, WSDL, SVC, ASAX, etc) files out of the source. Thanks again!

Comment: @surfjungle For Windows applications, there aren't any source or markup files to publish.  The directory where MSBuild puts the finished binaries contains everything a service or application needs.  Are there files you're seeing missing from the build output directory?

Comment: @ Splattered Bits. What's in the \release\bin directory after an MSBuild compile is mostly what I need; excepting the PDB files which, from what I remember, can be prevented from being compiled by an update to the CSPROJ file. For the Windows Application side of things, I was wondering if there was something similar to an MSBuild package whereby in addition to a compile, it will take the contents of the \release\bin directory and put it into our local distribution directory - I would like to standardise things rather than having to use NAnt to copy files around for 2 out of 5 compnent types.

Comment: @surfjungle You're stuck doing xcopy deploys.  You could package the `release\bin` directories into zip file and ship those around.

Comment: @ Splattered Bits. Thanks for the information but it's a pity, as MSBuild's package is so useful. From my perspective, it's hard to believe that Web Applications, Web Sites and Web Services can be so cleanly deployed but we're stuck jumping through hoops to do similar for Windows Services and Windows Applications. Looks like I'll be using NAnt for these Alas :)